# Extract partitions of images after edge detection

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Given a edge detected image like this:
[image: Image after edge detection]

I would like to extract each character into a sub-image, i.e so that each new picture only have one character. Is there a simple way of doing this in Mathematica? I figured since ContourDetect[] gives this:

[image: Contour Detected]

It appears that mathematica atleast have no problems of finding the actual contours.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4dN6.jpg"];
```

#### Binarize // MorphologicalTransform // ComponentMeasurements // ImageTrim

```
boxes = MorphologicalTransform[Binarize@img, "BoundingBoxes", ∞]
```

[image]

```
trim = ComponentMeasurements[boxes, "BoundingBox"][[All, -1]];

ImageTrim[img, trim]
```

[image]

Combining all steps in a function:

```
imgPartition = ImageTrim[#, 
   ComponentMeasurements[
       MorphologicalTransform[Binarize @ #, "BoundingBoxes", ∞], 
     "BoundingBox"][[All, -1]]] &;

imgPartition @ img
```

> same picture

Answer (score 8):

`MorphologicalComponents` seems like a promising way to go, like High Performance Mark says. So let's try it:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4dN6.jpg"];
MorphologicalComponents[img] // Colorize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We see here that there are more non-zero pixels (foreground pixels) than the original image lets on from looking at it. This causes `MorphologicalComponents` to find spurious components and to merge some components (like the two E characters.) Since those pixels are dark, we can guess that we can remove them using `Binarize`:

```
components = MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[img]];
components // Colorize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is better, but now there is another problem: there are smaller components inside some of the components, like sixes. We can remove these by first using `Dilation` to make sure that the border of the outer component is closed and then using `SelectComponents` to remove all components that are enclosed by some other component.

```
components = MorphologicalComponents[Dilation[Binarize[img], 1]];
components = SelectComponents[components, #EnclosingComponentCount == 0 &];
components // Colorize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now it looks like we found the right components. `ComponentMeasurements` can now be used to find the bounding boxes of the components and `ImageTrim` can be used to extract them from the image:

```
ComponentMeasurements[{img, components}, "Image"][[All, 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]